# Renormalization in non-perturbative QFT ($n$-point function)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, non-perturbative

How does one do renormalization if one can exactly calculate the $n$-point function of QFT?

Take for example QED when doing renormalization

- We calculate $2$ and $3$ point function
- Expand them in Feynamn series in order of coupling coefficient
- Use a regulator to remove very short length physics
- Renormalize the parameter($A_{\mu},\psi,e,m$) to remove the singularity at first order of renormalized coupling coefficient.

As seen from the above scheme the key point was removing infinity of $O(g)$ term where $g$ stands for coupling coefficient. So my question is how the scheme of renormalization will change if we can compute the $n$-point function exactly?

Of course, we have to do renormalization since we redefine our Lagrangian in terms of renormalized parameters. The bare parameters are not there in renormalized Lagrangian.

Comment: If you are basing your calculations in QFT on the evaluation of $n$-point correlation functions, you are *already* limiting yourself to a perturbative regime.  The nonperturbative $S$-matrix elements for the physical excitations of a theory do not reduce to $n$-point correlation functions of field operators.

Comment: This is the domain of [lattice field theory](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Lattice_quantum_field_theory) and [non-perturbative renormalization group methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_renormalization_group)

Comment: @Buzz I learned renormalization (QED only) recently so I know this yet. I understand when we get rid of IR divergence in QED the $n$-point function is not good as observable. I remember Schwartz mentioning observable is tough business in QFT. I have changed the title to mention it.

Comment: @Buzz To clarify: Why would evaluating $n$-point correlation functions imply limiting yourself to a perturbative regime? The correlation functions are nonperturbatively defined (assuming that the theory itself is nonperturbatively defined, of course), whether or not we have the mathematical technology to evaluate them nonperturbatively (and in some cases we do). Are you referring to our ability to calculate rather than our ability to define?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Because the correlation functions are not actually the objects of interest.  In a scattering process, what you actually want to know is the $S$-matrix element $S_{fi}=\langle\{p_{f}\}\,{\rm out}|\{p_{i}\}\,{\rm in}\rangle$.  The LSZ formula allows you to reduce this—perturbatively—to a correlation function $\langle 0|\phi(p_{f,1})\cdots\phi(p_{f,n_{f}})\phi(p_{i,1})\cdots\phi(p_{i,n_{i}})|0\rangle$.  However, this reduction cannot be performed (except in special cases) for the full nonperturbative theory; additional machinery is needed to supplement the correlation function.

Comment: @Buzz I see what you're saying about LSZ, but the question doesn't mention scattering, and the importance of renormalization isn't limited to scattering or to perturbation theory. The question only asks about $n$-point functions, with the condition "if we can compute the $n$-point function exactly."

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Whether it they are scattering amplitudes or anything else, the **physical observables** in a nonperturbative theory cannot in general be calculated with $n$-point correlations functions, which is all my original comment said:  "If you are basing your calculations in QFT on the evaluation of $n$-point correlation functions, you are already limiting yourself to a perturbative regime."